# If an app exists in multiple repositories, which one gets installed?

Tags: raspberrypi, ubuntu-mate

Simple question... if an app, say Chromium exists in multiple repositories. Which one is downloaded and installed using 'apt-get install chromium-browser'.

Update: I'm running Ubuntu-Mate on a RaspberryPi3 and trying to get Chromium working. It seems like there is a working version of Chromium available through the Raspbian repositories, but because the version on the Ubuntu repositories is newer it installs the newer version (as has been answered below), which doesn't work at present with Ubuntu-Mate.

I've been getting errors when trying to manually download and install the Raspbian version. Which had me wondering if there was another alternative to get it.

Comment: The higher version.

Comment: Thanks... is there a way to select which repository is used?

Comment: That's not how it works. Apps can be pinned to a certain version which means it won't update even if an newer version is detected (regardless of the origin). If you don't want software from a certain repository just remove it. If however you need it for a piece of software but not other than perhaps you should think about what you're trying to do. Being completely honest, if you really needed such packet micro-management you would have a reason for that, would know what I just told you and a lot more and wouldb't be here asking. I have a feeling you're about to do something not smart...

Comment: Perhaps it would be better for you to [edit] the question, describe your goal/issue/ idea, whatever, and ask about how to accomplish it instead of what you *think* is a solution.

Comment: And I was right... No, you shouldn't even try to do that, ever. By "that" I mean installing packages that are **not for your distro**.

Comment: And you're again asking about something you think is a solution instead about the real issue: Chromium isn't working. So, what happens? Have you tried to run it terminal already? Please post the entire error messages.

Comment: I've uninstalled Chromium and am re-downloading it based on a different set of instructions posted here: [link](https://ubuntu-mate.community/t/tutorial-install-working-chromium-50/6762). Internet connection is a bit slow, will update further after the download and installation is complete.

Comment: Was never able to install based on instructions in previous post, kept receiving un-met dependency errors. So I went back and installed through Synaptic. Installation appeared to run ok, but when starting Chromium I receive the following error (too long to post in this message).